# C# Winform Label reversed on Vista

Tags: .net, label

I develop and compile a Winform Application in C# with a unmanaged C++ library on a XP computer.
This application works perfectly under XP.

On **Vista**, everything works fine (launching the C++ DLL, results and curve displaying, ...)  except a **problem of displaying the text of the Label component**.

**F (t/m)** is displayed  **(F (t/m**

**El (%)** is displayed   **(%) El**

**Ra [Ra]** is displayed   **[Ra [Ra**

These 3 values correspond to the text Properties of the 3 Label Component. These values are directly done on the designer, no coding.

Do someone have an idea to fix this problem?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your problem reminds me of one I've had years ago - it has to do with the RTL (right-to-left) property of the control. Could you have, by mistake, turned RTL to 'true' on the label controls, or anywhere else inside the DLL?